# How to select only p and not the span in css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I try to find the good selector to separate my span and my p

Someone have an idea plz ?

```
<div class="item-content-text">
  <p>
     <span>Jacob Thompson</span> has joined your group Chess Club
  </p>
</div>
```

## First Try

```
.item-content-text p:not(span) {
  
}
```

## Second Try

```
.item-content-text p {

}

.item-content-text span {
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item-content-text p {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.item-content-text span {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="item-content-text">
  <p>
    <span>Jacob Thompson</span> has joined your group Chess Club
  </p>
</div>
```